# SQL with as expression shows multiple results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a SQL query using `with as` expression. I always get a result in the square of what I required.

This is my query:

```
DECLARE @MAX_DATE AS INT

SET @MAX_DATE = (SELECT DATEPART(MONTH,FECHA) FROM ALBVENTACAB WHERE NUMALBARAN IN (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(NUMALBARAN) FROM ALBVENTACAB));

;WITH TABLE_LAST AS (
SELECT CONCAT(DATEPART(MONTH,FECHA),'-',DATEPART(YEAR,FECHA)) as LAST_YEAR_MONTH
,SUM(TOTALNETO) AS LAST_YEAR_VALUE
FROM ALBVENTACAB
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) -1 = DATEPART(YEAR,FECHA) AND NUMSERIE LIKE 'A%'
AND DATEPART(MONTH,FECHA) <= @MAX_DATE
GROUP BY CONCAT(DATEPART(MONTH,FECHA),'-',DATEPART(YEAR,FECHA))
)

,TABLE_CURRENT AS(
SELECT CONCAT(DATEPART(MONTH,FECHA),'-',DATEPART(YEAR,FECHA)) as CURR_YEAR_MONTH
,SUM(TOTALNETO) AS CURR_YEAR_VALUE
FROM ALBVENTACAB
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) <= DATEPART(YEAR,FECHA) AND NUMSERIE LIKE 'A%'
GROUP BY CONCAT(DATEPART(MONTH,FECHA),'-',DATEPART(YEAR,FECHA))
)
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_CURRENT, TABLE_LAST
```

When I run the query I get exactly the square of the result.

I want to compare sale monthly with last year.

```
2-2020  814053.3    2-2019  840295.1
1-2020  1094993.65  2-2019  840295.1
3-2020  293927.3    2-2019  840295.1
2-2020  814053.3    1-2019  1050701.68
1-2020  1094993.65  1-2019  1050701.68
3-2020  293927.3    1-2019  1050701.68
2-2020  814053.3    3-2019  887776.1
1-2020  1094993.65  3-2019  887776.1
3-2020  293927.3    3-2019  887776.1
```

I should get only 3 rows instead of 9 rows.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. You're selecting from both CTEs - **without** providing any join condition between them - so you'll get each row of `TABLE_CURRENT` combined with each row of `TABLE_LAST` - a cartesian product, and typically **not** what you really want !

Comment: But data is on the same table. How Can I use join? I am not very much familiar with SQL.

Comment: The data is in two different views, TABLE_CURRENT and TABLE_LAST. The comma is short for `CROSS JOIN`, so you have `table_current CROSS JOIN table_last`. You want an inner join or some outer join instead.

Comment: I think you meant to use `=`, not `<=` in your "current year" query. You should use date ranges  rather than calling a function on your table values to extract the year

Comment: @CaiusJard actually this query will be generic and will work for years. Date range I can not mention. Further, this is the sale table with each day stored. I want to show a sales comparison monthly compares to last year.

Comment: Can happen that one month is missing from a year, e.g. no sales in February 2019? What would you want to show in such a situation?

Comment: @Fawad none of that is relevant to the point I'm making. If you ask SQLServer to execute a function on row data in a where clause, then it must be executed for every row, every time the query runs. If your table has a million rows a year then 2 million function calls must be executed every time the query runs, and indexes on the row data cannot be used. This is a massive performance hit, all for the sake of not bothering to parameterize the query and use ranges. `WHERE fecha > @fromDate and fecha < @toDate` is the same thing as `WHERE YEAR(fecha) = @year`

Comment: @ThorstenKettner that will not be the case. There will be sales every month.

Comment: @Fawad throsten's point is valid; you can script things to be able to handle the case of a zero sales month *and you should* because you can *never* say "there will always be sales". If the admin installs your program and picks the query to run at 1 millisecond past midnight on the first of the month, suddenly all the reported dales from that month last year, will disappear.. Try very hard to make things as idiotproof as you can, because the universe is great at supplying better idiots than we can code for. When it's as simple as using FULL OUTER JOIN, it's worth doing

Comment: @CaiusJard how I can parameterize? I have no idea which date or month this report will run. The only thing I, if it runs in 2020 it should give 2019 data as well for comparison. If it runs in 2021 it should give data of 2020 for comparison.

Comment: The same way you do now; you use sql servers clock. The documentation says "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is nondeterministic". The documentation also says "nondeterministic functions cannot be folded" - folding means that SQLServer will calculate a value early on and use it repeatedly. As such, with timestamp you should probably stash the value in a variable and use the variable..

Comment: But the main point I'm making is **don't extract the YEAR from every fecha and compare it to extracting the year from the current timestamp**, declare a variable and set it by converting a string(probably the easiest way in sqls2008) eg `DECLARE @startThisYear DATETIME; SET @startThisYear = CONVERT(DATETIME, YEAR(GETDATE())+'0101'` at the top of the query - do the same for next and prev year by add/sub 1 to `YEAR(GETDATE())` then you can run your queries as `WHERE fecha >= @start1YearAgo AND fecha < @startThisYear` and  `WHERE fecha >= @startThisYear AND fecha < @startNextYear`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly **join** your two CTE - the way you're doing it now, you're getting a **Cartesian product** of each row in either CTE together.

Do something like:

```
*;WITH TABLE_LAST AS 
( .... 
),
TABLE_CURRENT AS
( .... 
)
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_CURRENT curr
INNER JOIN TABLE_LAST last ON (some join condition here)
```

What that join condition is going to be - I have no idea, and cannot tell from your question - but you have to **define** how these two sets of data "connect" ....

It could be something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_CURRENT curr
INNER JOIN TABLE_LAST last ON curr.CURR_YEAR_MONTH = last.LAST_YEAR_MONT
```

or whatever else makes sense in your situation - but basically, you need to somehow "tie together" these two sets of data and get only those rows that make sense - not just every row from "last" combined with every row from "curr" ....

Comment: I have a table with sales stored in each day. I have to combine the sale monthly, and for the same last year I have to show for comparison.

Comment: @Fawad please refine your question rather than scattering your requirements across comments on answers (that may end up deleted when you refine your requirements)

Comment: @marc-s might also need some advice on using an outer join so that no records from one interval doesn't kill a report of records from a related interval. Also wanted to point out that because the columns you've cited in your ON are potentially from different years (when the `<=` bug is resolved) this could produce no rows, or only produce rows that are the same year data restated?

Comment: @marc_s Thank you for your help. I figure out how to solve this after your inner join query.

Answer (score 1):

While you already got the answer on how to join the two results, I thought I'd tell you how to typically approach such problems.

From the same table, you want two sums on different conditions (different years that is). You solve this with conditional aggregation, which does just that: aggregate (sum) based on a condition (year).

```
select
  datepart(month, fecha) as month,
  sum(case when datepart(year, fecha) = datepart(year, getdate()) then totalneto end) as this_year,
  sum(case when datepart(year, fecha) = datepart(year, getdate()) -1 then totalneto end) as last_year
from albventacab
where numserie like 'A%' 
  and fecha > dateadd(year, -2, getdate())
group by datepart(month, fecha)
order by datepart(month, fecha);
```

Comment: Can I end this result base on the current month only?

Comment: Something like `and datepart(month, fecha) = datepart(month, getdate())` or `and datepart(month, fecha) <= datepart(month, getdate())`?